# DatePicker getDateFormat is not applicable

Tags: android, datepicker

Still being a newby I have an issue with the DatePicker.
I call the DatePicker by OnClick or when the EditText has focus. When the user picks a date I want to show it in the EditText formatted to the currently set user locale of the system.

I've done following code but eclipse says that 'getDateFormat' is not applicable.

I hope you can help me to fix this issue because I really don't understand the problem.

I'm even not sure if it's correct waht I did with the string 'selectedDate'.

Thanks!

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if (v == txtDate) {
        if(hasFocus == true){

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in edit text
                        String selectedDate = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = sdf.parse(selectedDate);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // handle exception here !
                        }
                        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
                        String s = dateFormat.format(date);
                        txtDate.setText(s);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to [getDateFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat(android.content.Context)) must be a `android.content.Context`. You are passing a `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` instance instead. If this code is inside an `Activity` named `Foo`, try passing `Foo.this` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your swift reply! Indeed, this was the issue with the argument - I always mess up with context :-(

Comment: @ cybersam If you don't mind, I now get a null pointer exception at

Comment: `String s = dateFormat.format(date);`
`txtDate.setText(s);`